# Filtering JSON data with the same name

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm using JSON in Google Sheets to lookup a Zip and find the county. I only want the county returned. I can get it to return every value so the ImportJSON function is working.

Here's my formula. I've tried all permutations of the reference but I just don't know how to format it.

```
=ImportJSON(CONCATENATE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="92660), "results/address_components/long_name[3]", "noHeaders")
```

Here's the JSON data from Google Maps Geocoding API. I only want the county long name. In this example it's, "Orange County".

```
{
       "results" : [
          {
             "address_components" : [
                {
                   "long_name" : "92660",
                   "short_name" : "92660",
                   "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Newport Beach",
                   "short_name" : "Newport Beach",
                   "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "Orange County",
                   "short_name" : "Orange County",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "California",
                   "short_name" : "CA",
                   "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                },
                {
                   "long_name" : "United States",
                   "short_name" : "US",
                   "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                }
             ],
             "formatted_address" : "Newport Beach, CA 92660, USA",
             "geometry" : {
                "bounds" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : 33.671823,
                      "lng" : -117.841337
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : 33.6040739,
                      "lng" : -117.909447
                   }
                },
                "location" : {
                   "lat" : 33.6301328,
                   "lng" : -117.8721676
                },
                "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport" : {
                   "northeast" : {
                      "lat" : 33.671823,
                      "lng" : -117.841337
                   },
                   "southwest" : {
                      "lat" : 33.6040739,
                      "lng" : -117.909447
                   }
                }
             },
             "place_id" : "ChIJRdSajSne3IAR8T4A2x-wgrE",
             "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 things that are preventing it to properly import:

1. specifically in the concatenate function you have `address="92660`

which should be `address=",92660`

or you can eliminate the concat function altogether and format the url like this:

`"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="&"92660"`

or technically point to the cell such as A1 with the `92660` value e.g. `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="&A1`

2. your missing the beginning `/` in front of `results`
3. In order to get the 3rd item, instead of using `[3]` , wrap your formula in the index function and reference the index of `3`

the full thing:

`=index(importjson("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="&A1,"/results/address_components/long_name","noHeaders"),3)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. It turns out that Google's addresses aren't all in the same order but, that's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of details, but what about just parsing the json, and then doing results["address_components"][2]["long_name"]?

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting a "Formula parse error."   `=ImportJSON(CONCATENATE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",C2), "results["address_components"][2]["long_name"]", "noHeaders")`  If I remove the quotes, I get a "Reference not found error"    `=ImportJSON(CONCATENATE("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",C2), "results[address_components][2][long_name]", "noHeaders")`